# difference between MicrosoftMvcValidation.debug.js and MicrosoftMvcValidation.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation

What is the difference between MicrosoftMvcValidation.debug.js and MicrosoftMvcValidation.js?
(I know the file is smaller) I ask this because I don't find Sys_Mvc_FieldContext$validate in MicrosoftMvcValidation.js.

In this blogpost (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) I have to add something to the function Sys_Mvc_FieldContext$validate in the debug file. I also want to add it in the 'normal' file.

thanks,

Filip